# Master slave replication in mysql seconds behind master goes on increasing

Tags: mysql-5.5

In replication at slave end seconds_behind_master goes on increasing.
The dump file for upload is of 6.7 gb large, can it be the reason for the lagging of seconds behind master?

Answer (score 3):

Just check if you have same time and timezones on both the servers, i.e., Master as well as Slave.

++++++++
Here is an idea

In order for you to know that MySQL is fully processing the SQL from the relay logs. Try the following:

STOP SLAVE IO_THREAD;
This will stop replication from downloading new entries from the master into its relay logs.

The other thread, known as the SQL thread, will continue processing the SQL statements it downloaded from the master.

When you run SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G, keep your eye on Exec_Master_Log_Pos. Run SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G again. If Exec_Master_Log_Pos does not move after a minute, you can go ahead run START SLAVE IO_THREAD;. This may reduce the number of Seconds_Behind_Master.

Other than that, there is really nothing you can do except to:

Trust Replication
Monitor Seconds_Behind_Master
Monitor Exec_Master_Log_Pos
Run SHOW PROCESSLIST;, take note of the SQL thread to see if it is processing long running queries.
BTW Keep in mind that when you run SHOW PROCESSLIST; with replication running, there should be two DB Connections whose user name is system user. One of those DB Connections will have the current SQL statement being processed by replication. As long as a different SQL statement is visible each time you run SHOW PROCESSLIST;, you can trust mysql is still replicating properly.

Comment: The time-related issues weren't my problem.  However, the tip to monitor `Exec_Mater_Log_Pos` was a good one.  Turns out our slave isn't frozen, just processing a lot of queries that were executed essentially at the same moment.

Answer (score 3):

We had this issue on a production server tonight and it turns out a query was blocking replication.  We killed the process that was blocking replication and the second_behind_master caught up.  We found the process by analyzing the results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the exact same issue before.

Please make the following changes to rectify "Seconds_Behind_Master" increasing once slave has started.

Firstly check the "trx" value on slave server

- show variables like '%trx%';

if the value of "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit" is "1" as below

- Variable_name                             | Value |
- innodb_api_trx_level                      | 0     |
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1     |
- innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON    |

then change this value to "2"

- set global innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2;

Once you've changed this in your mysql client also change this in your my.cnf file to ensure that once mysql restarts this value persists.

- vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

search for "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1"

and change its value to "2" as well.

This will resolve your "Seconds_Behind_Master" issue.